# Удаление элемента в jQuery по условию

Tags: jquery

Есть **div** элементы с классом **placeholder**, в каждом есть **data-price** со значением, по этому значению нужно оставить всё, что больше 30000 и меньше 40000.

```
$(".placeholder").data('price') //*Выдаёт значение price с первого div*
```

Можно удалить\скрыть всё что больше 30000 и меньше 40000 через функцию по значению `.data('price')`, но правильно оформить у меня не выходит :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я любитель чистого `JavaScript`. Поэтому вдруг пригодится.

```js
var items = document.querySelectorAll(".placeholder");
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    var data_info = +items[i].dataset.price;
    if (data_info > 30000 && data_info < 40000) items[i].style.display="none";
}
```

```html
<div class="placeholder" data-price="33000">33000</div>
<div class="placeholder" data-price="20000">20000</div>
<div class="placeholder" data-price="45000">45000</div>
<div class="placeholder" data-price="35000">35000</div>
```

Comment: у вопроса не просто так стоит метка jquery :) ну и можно было без второго цикла тогда уж обойтись

Comment: @Grundy, ну так то да. Я просто оставлю здесь свой ответ)

Comment: @Regent, да, косяк мой, признаю)

Comment: @Артем про чистоту JS момент остаётся, но это уж больно тонкая материя, до которой большинству нет дела. В принципе, вариант без jQuery в данном случае выглядит конкурентоспособным.

Comment: @Regent, "Чистым" я имел в виду - без использования `JQuery`(не люблю его)

Comment: @Артем Спасибо большое! На JS даже лучше ))

Answer (score 2):

Здесь нужно использовать функцию [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) и оставить только те, которые надо удалить/скрыть

```
var items = $(".placeholder").filter(function(index, el){
    var price = +$(el).data('price'); // получаем цену элемента
    return price > 30000 && price < 40000; //оставляем его в наборе при следующих условиях
});

items.remove();// удалить все выбранные;
items.hide();// скрыть все выбранные;
```

Comment: " нужно оставить всё, что больше 30000 и меньше 40000" и "Можно удалить\скрыть всё что больше 30000 и меньше 40000" - это, по-моему, здорово. А почему вы всё же решили остановиться на варианте с "можно", а не с "нужно"?

Comment: @Regent, я решил, что _оставить_ - это типа в отфильтрованной коллекции, и потом эти оставленные удалить :-) Но в принципе любой вариант получается заменой условия, я надеюсь автор разберется :-)

Comment: Да, возможно, имеет такой смысл за этими словами и кроется :)